# Is possible to use SimpleXML in conjunction with SAX to generate XML in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, simple-framework

I have some legacy code that uses SAX to produce well formatted XML.

I was wondering if it would be possible to generate a branch of this document using SimpleXML instead.

If i try to attach the XML generated with SimpleXML to the SAX parser as a normal text,  characters like '<' are converted to their numeric reference.

Does anyone knows if there is a way to attach well encoded XML as well?

Comment: Can you change any input- or escapingsettings in your parser?